# Creating a second servlet using Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have an application developed in Spring boot and I have the following `Application` class in which I register a `FacesServlet`. All good until now, but I need a second servlet.

I can't manage to register and set the mappings for this new servlet.

I searched over and over through the posts but I found nothing helpful.

Here is my Application class in which I register the second servlet, Login servlet:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"at.bdt"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"at.bdt.persist.repository"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"at.bdt.persist.model"}) 
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements ServletContextAware
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean facesServlet()
    {
        FacesServlet servlet = new FacesServlet();
        ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new  ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "*.xhtml");
        servletRegistrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return servletRegistrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ConfigureListener> jsfConfigureListener()
    {
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ConfigureListener>(new ConfigureListener());
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean(){
        LoginServlet lg=new LoginServlet();
        ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBeanLog = new ServletRegistrationBean(lg, "/LoginServlet");
    //  servletRegistrationBeanLog.addUrlMappings("/LoginServlet");
        servletRegistrationBeanLog.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return servletRegistrationBeanLog;
    }


/*  @Bean
    public MessageSource message()
    {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }*/
    @Bean
    public CustomScopeConfigurer registerViewScope()
    {
        CustomScopeConfigurer configurer = new CustomScopeConfigurer();
        Map<String, Object> scopes = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        scopes.put("view", new ViewScope());
        configurer.setScopes(scopes);
        return configurer;
    }
    @Override
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext sc)
    {
    }
}"
```

This is my servlet:

```
@WebServlet(
        description = "Login Servlet", 
        urlPatterns = { "/LoginServlet" })
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public void init() throws ServletException {

    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        //get request parameters for userID and password
        String user = request.getParameter("user");
        String pwd = request.getParameter("pwd");


            response.sendRedirect("LoginSuccess.jsp");
       }

    }

}
```

The servlet is written just for testing purposes for now. I just want to see

login.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="US-ASCII">
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="LoginServlet" method="post">

Username: <input type="text" name="user">
<br>
Password: <input type="password" name="pwd">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

LoginSuccess.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
    pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Login Success Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Hi Doris, Login successful.</h3>
<a href="login.html">Login Page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not using a `web.xml` file, I use spring boot to register the servlets.
When I access http://localhost:8080/web/views/LoginServlet/login.html

I get the following error:

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Apr 05 09:09:23 CEST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

I've tried to access it as: http://localhost:8080/web/views/LoginServlet
No success.

I just want to register a second servlet and make it functional, but I can't manage this with spring boot.
I can't figure how to set the url mappings.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The URL is `/LoginServlet` see your code, your `/web/views` shouldn't be in there.

Comment: HTPP status 404  /LoginServlet/login.html
type Status report

message /LoginServlet/login.html

description The requested resource is not available.

Comment: Also why a separate servlet? You are using JSF why not use that? Also you don't want to access your servlet but the html page which should be served by Spring Boot. IMHO you are making things to complex by adding all that stuff. Either use a simple Spring controller and let the `DispatcherServlet` handle it or use JSF...

Comment: I have the login.html file and LoginSuccess.jsp under src/main/webapp/views. Should I move them? Because if I remove the web/views/ part from the URL I get the error described in my previous comment. Thank you a lot for your reply.

Comment: I am trying to implement the login for my app and I thought to do it using a servlet, but I guess a spring controller should be better.

Comment: I just wanted to see how to register a second servlet in a spring boot app.

Comment: I didn't manage to use a second servlet in a spring boot app and I was very curious about.

Comment: The issue isn't your servlet but how you want to access your pages.